# JtextArea get Line number from the displayed contents

Tags: java, jtextarea

- I have a **JtextArea in a scrollPane**.
- I need to get the line count of the line which is displayed first and not the actual beginning line.
- If I have **1000** lines and currently **JTextArea** is displaying 500 - 550 lines in UI
- I need to get the number 500 which is the first line in display.

Is it possible to achieve it?

Comment: See if you can manipulate from this http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/23/text-component-line-number/

Comment: @Hirak It displays line number but i couldnt able to get the line number of first line which is displayed